# Porque eu não consigo comparar um objeto com outro objeto?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código bem simples

```
var x = new String("html");
var y = new String("html");

window.alert(x == y);
```

E ele me retorna semple *false* é possível eu realizar a comparação entre dois objetos? E porque eu não posso comparar dois objetos sendo que ambos são iguais?

Answer (score 4):

Bem os objectos são tratados como referência, ou apontador de memória, por isso, não é possível usar === ou == para comparar os dois. Uma maneira rápida de comparar os dois objetos é ver se têm o mesmo valor na chave. Isto pode ser feito usando JSON.stringify. Outra maneira é usar a função Lodash isEqual.

```
const ob1 = {obj: 'A'};
const ob2 = {obj: 'A'};

// JavaScript
JSON.stringify(ob1) === JSON.stringify(ob2); // true

// Lodash
_.isEqual(ob1, ob2); // true
```

Uma nota no caso de escolher usar o `JSON.stringify()` tenha em atenção que a ordem das coisas (o par chave valor) é importante, por isso se não estiverem nos objetos na mesma ordem o resultado vai ser diferente.